Azure: Add Sensitivity Label to Azure Group through Powershell
I'm looking to add a Sensitivity Label to an Azure group. The Microsoft documentation says the option should appear right when I create the group:

But that is not the case for me when I go to create a group:

I found this website that says it needs to be activated in Powershell before that option becomes available. I ran that code but got errors. I'm wondering if anyone knows a Powershell script to activate the Sensitivity Labels in Azure Groups? Or if there is any other way to add Sensitivity Labels to groups. Thank you.

To add a Sensitivity Label to an Azure group, you need to ensure that all the following conditions are met, as per the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/groups-assign-sensitivity-labels?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_IAM#troubleshooting-issues

The organization has an active Microsoft Entra ID P1 license.
The feature is enabled and EnableMIPLabels is set to True in the Microsoft Graph PowerShell module.
The sensitivity labels are published in the Microsoft Purview portal or the Microsoft Purview compliance portal for this Microsoft Entra organization.
Labels are synchronized to Microsoft Entra ID with the Execute-AzureAdLabelSync cmdlet in the Security & Compliance PowerShell module. It can take up to 24 hours after synchronization for the label to be available to Microsoft Entra ID.

The sensitivity label scope must be configured for Groups & Sites.
The group is a Microsoft 365 group.
The current signed-in user has sufficient privileges to assign sensitivity labels. The user must be the group owner or at least a group administrator.

To enable Sensitivity Label to Microsoft 365 Groups , you need to have atleast, Microsoft Entra ID P1 license.
Make sure that EnableMIPLabels is set to be True in the Microsoft Graph Powershell Module.
Install-Module Azure AD

Import-Azure AD Module

$Settings = Get-AzureADDirectorySetting -Id (Get-AzureADDirectorySetting | where -Property DisplayName -Value "Group.Unified" -EQ).id

$Settings.Values



Note: If the value of EnableMIPLabels is not set to be true, set it by using following command.
$Settings["EnableMIPLabels"]="True"
Set-AzureADDirectorySetting -Id $Settings.Id -DirectorySetting $Settings

After setting the EnableMIPLabels, it needs to be synchronized. Synchronize by following command
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-IPPSSession -UserPrincipalName <UPN>
Execute-AzureADLabelSync

After setting and synchronizing labels, Need to create and publish the Labels in MicrosoftPurviewPortal
Adding the snapshots, What I configure to get Successfully Sensitivity label added to Microsoft 365 groups.
First, You need to crete Labels, Login in to purview portal --> Select Information Protection--> Labels--> Create Labels
Label Details: Add Name for your Sensitivity label.

Scope: Define scope for your sensitivity label i.e  Items and Groups and  Sites.

Items: Assign permissions, to whom the sensitivity label will applicable i.e, for all users and group, for specific users and group,

**Groups and Sites:**Define protection settings for groups and sites.


Schematized data assest (preview): Not Enabled
After Creating label successfully, Need to publish that label or Create policy for it.
Follow below mentioned steps:
Select Publish Label --> Choose Sensitivity Labels to Publish-->Add

Assign admin units,  Admin units = Full directory

Users and groups: Select the scope of users and groups.

Settings:

I selected by default settings for documents, emails, meeting, and Fabric Power BI.
For Sites and Groups Setting, I selected Sensitivity Label which I created.

Give a name to your policy.
My whole configuration:

After, successfully publishing the policy, It can take upto 24hrs to reflect to Microsoft 365 groups.
Output:


Refer Docs:
AddSensitivityLabel
TroubleShootingIssue
